# What is this goblin spell that’s been wrecking me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

I am getting wrecked by goblin shamans. They just stretch their staff towards me and my health starts dropping like crazy. Sometimes I get 2 of them, but the third one inevitably gets me. I try to figure out what spell it is, so as to take counter measures. I don’t see any sparks or fire. I have searched the spells available to me, but I cannot conclude anything before activating all.

Next time I try to take a screenshot, but it is extremely difficult during battles.

**Is there any icon that could tell me, what condition is afflicting me?**

It seems to be happening independently of whether I attack, block or just wait.

I further attempted to find their spell list online. So far unsuccessfully.

Comment: Is it a frost spell? The only major types of Destruction magic are Fire, Shock, and Ice. If it is not an ice spell, then it could be a Damage Health effect, in which requires a Magic Resistance (based on my knowledge from previous Elder Scrolls games)

Comment: @TheMattbat999 yeah. That would have been the case in those games. But such spell doesn’t seem to be available to me. Perhaps it’s restricted to them?

Answer (score 2):

By your description this seems to be [Consuming Inferno](https://guides.gamepressure.com/the-elder-scrolls-blades/guide.asp?ID=50383#NH3_7), but it could also be [Wall of Fire](https://guides.gamepressure.com/the-elder-scrolls-blades/guide.asp?ID=50383#NH3_12).
If it's the first, then try to break it with an ability like Shield Slam, if it's the latter, then just don't attack with your weapon while the effect is active and you should be fine.
Anyway, getting some fire protection enchantments on your gear will also help to reduce the damage.

Comment: It definitely happens even if I just block. So consuming inferno could be it

Comment: Could also be poison cloud. Now that I unlocked that and see the targets health melting away, I think that’s what they directed at me

Comment: Now that I unlocked poison cloud, I think the shaman‘s Audio effect is identical to it’s bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on [this Reddit post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/ElderScrollsBlades/comments/bh1405/goblin_shaman_is_killing_me/), it seems to be a type of Fire Spell that is easily avoidable by backing away and letting the effect end. Just keep your distance whenever they ready up the spell, run in during their down time and hit them, rinse and repeat until the Shamans are dead.
EDIT:
As mentioned in the post also, don't try to attack while the spell is active. It seems to hurt you.